# angularjs directive unit test fail with controllerAs, bindToController & isolateScope()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive, isolate-scope, controlleras

I am trying to unit test a directive with a two-way bound property (=). The directive works in my app, but I can't get a unit test working that tests the two-way binding.

I have been trying to get this working for days. I've read MANY examples that use some but not all of the features I want to use: controllerAs, bindToController & isolateScope(). (Forget about templateURL, which I also need. I will add that if I can get this working! :)

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to show a change in the parent scope reflected in the isolate scope.

Here is a plunkr that contains the code below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JQl9fB5kTt1CPtZymwhI

Here is my test app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('greetingController', greetingController);
greetingController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function greetingController($scope) {
  // this controller intentionally left blank (for testing purposes)
}

angular.module('myApp').directive('greetingDirective',
        function () {
            return {
                scope: {testprop: '='},
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div>Greetings!</div>',
                controller: 'greetingController',
                controllerAs: 'greetingController',
                bindToController: true
            };
        }
);
```

And here is the spec:

```
describe('greetingController', function () {

var ctrl, scope, rootScope, controller, data, template,
        compile, isolatedScope, element;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {

    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    scope = rootScope.$new();
    controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    compile = $injector.get('$compile');

    data = {
        testprop: 1
    };

    ctrl = controller('greetingController', {$scope: scope}, data);
    element = angular.element('<greeting-directive testprop="testprop"></greeting-directive>');
    template = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();

}));

// PASSES
it('testprop inital value should be 1', function () {
    expect(ctrl.testprop).toBe(1);
});

// FAILS: why doesn't changing this isolateScope value 
// also change the controller value for this two-way bound property?
it('testprop changed value should be 2', function () {
    isolatedScope.testprop = 2;
    expect(ctrl.testprop).toBe(2);
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to correct the way you're testing your directive. You're directly changing `isolatedScope` of an object and thereafter verifying the `ctrl` object which unrelated `DOM` which you had compiled.

Basically what you should be doing is as soon as you compiled a DOM with scope (here it is `<greeting-directive testprop="testprop"></greeting-directive>`). So that scope will hold the context of compiled do. In short you can play `testprop` property value. or same thing will be available inside `element.scope()`. As soon as you change any value in `scope`/`currentScope`. You can see the value gets updated inside directive `isolatedScope`. One more thing I'd like to mention is when you do `controllerAs` with `bindToController: true`, angular adds property with controller alias inside `scope` that's we verified `isolatedScope.greetingController.testprop` inside `assert`

**Code**

```
describe('greetingController', function() {

  var ctrl, scope, rootScope, controller, data, template,
    compile, isolatedScope, currentScope, element;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    scope = rootScope.$new();
    controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    compile = $injector.get('$compile');

    data = { testprop: 1 };

    ctrl = controller('greetingController', { $scope: scope }, data);
    element = angular.element('<greeting-directive testprop="testprop"></greeting-directive>');
    template = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    currentScope = element.scope();
    //OR
    //currentScope = scope; //both are same
    isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();
  }));

  // First test passes -- commented

  it('testprop changed value should be 2', function() {
    currentScope.testprop = 2; //change current element (outer) scope value
    currentScope.$digest(); //running digest cycle to make binding effects
    //assert
    expect(isolatedScope.greetingController.testprop).toBe(2);
  });

});
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SQeHG1o0SewS3QOVPqU?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness and expertise. This is so very helpful to me. Thank you! May you be blessed with prosperity and riches on all levels.

Comment: @DanBKC Hey, thanks mate for blessing, since years I'm helping other fellows. But you're the one who gave such a good comment, Thanks ;) It encouraged me to do more contribution :)